# Locking down a command to a specific Role

Tags: discord.js

I have a created a command as shown below, I want it so only "Founder/Leader" role is able to use it so it won't be abused.

This is my code so far but I'm lost as how to make it so only I can do it.

```
    if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('!priv')) {
      let text = msg.content.slice('!priv'.length); // cuts off the /private part
      msg.guild.members.forEach(member => {
        if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text);
    return;
      });
    }
  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```js
    if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('!priv')) {
      const fetchedRole = msg.guild.roles.find((r) => r.name.toLowerCase() === 'founder/leader'); // fetch the role

      if (!msg.member.roles.has(fetchedRole.id)) return msg.reply('You don\'t have the founder/leader role!'); // if the member of the message has not the role with the above fetched name, the bot throws an error (error message)
      let text = msg.content.slice('!priv'.length); // cuts off the /private part
      msg.guild.members.forEach(member => {
        if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text);
        return;
      });
    }
```

First, you have to fetch the role that the message member must have. After this step, simply check if `msg.member.roles` has the role you fetched and that's it!

Comment: @Torment Nice to hear! If it worked you can mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Done :) Sorry getting used to the website haha! I'm sure you'll see a few more topics from me in the near future ^.^